# Using an OR conditional when using Angular filters

Tags: angularjs

I just started working with Angularjs and I'm facing the following problem:

I get this kind of object from an API request:

```
{
  "recid": "1576",
  "title": "19th Century UK Periodicals",
  "description": "Bevat ruim 180 gescande tijdschriften die full text doorzoekbaar zijn",
  "type": "tek",
  "tags": "Engeland",
  "primair": "b:bio",
  "secundair": "h:eng,h:ges",
},
```

And I need to filter by selecting data that belongs to 'primair' OR 'secundair' field, how could I do that since chaining uses a sort of AND intead of Or.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use a custom filter function. In your controller you would define it like this:

```
 function YourController ($scope) {
   $scope.filterFn = function (v) {
     return (v.primair === 'somevalue') || (s.secundair === 'someothervalue');
   };
 }
```

In your template you can use it like this:

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in yourlist | filter:filterFn">{{item.title}}</li>
```

Comment: I'm not so sure this is a good way to declare a filter.  I would use `angular.module('myModule',[]).filter('myFilter',function(){ ... })`

Comment: Oh man, that was awesome !!!
Even though it was not the exact answer I was looking for thanks to your answer I was able to figure out what to do.
Thanks man, your help save me hours hitting my head against the desk.
:-)